# phpmailer is working on localhost but not in my windows server(plesk onyx)

Tags: phpmailer, plesk-onyx

phpmailer is working on my localhost(wamp server) but not in my windows server(plesk onyx).

**Could not instantiate mail function.**

i got this error on my windows server.
i need to change my php.ini file?

anyone can help me please

Comment: i am newbie to windows server.

Comment: Apparently new to [reading documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) too.

Comment: Thank You :)  @Synchro for your reply. i read documentation it seems due to sendmail_path in php.ini

Comment: for windows server(plesk)  what should be my configuration path of sendmail_path??

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify `sendmail_path` on Windows Server.

To send mail using PHP script, you should allow mail relay for localhost. It can be done by adding localhost addresses via Plesk in **Tools & Settings > Mail Server Settings > White List**:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
```

[image]

Or directly to mail server software. For MailEnable, open MailEnable management console, follow the path **MailEnable Managment > Servers > localhost > Services and Connectors (or Connectors) >** right click on **SMTP > Properties > Relay**, make sure that **Allow Mail Relay**, **Allow relay for authenticated senders** and **Allow relay for privileged IP ranges** boxes are checked, and add `127.0.0.1` to **Privileged IPs...**.

[image]

Comment: I add my localhost address to white list but still not working